# QGIS Multiple Maps does not export correct

Tags: qgis

I have two maps on the printcompser I want to export as an .jpg image. The one map renders fine, but the inserted maps does not render correctly (google image via openlayers ). It renders in the print composer, but once I export  it the inserted maps is wrong. Both layers (layers have the same  CRS : EPSG 3857 WSG 84 Pseudo Mercator). To illustrate I include both the images from the print composer (correct) and the exported image (wrong). Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Print composer :
[image]

Exported image :
[image]

Regards

Comment: Exporting openlayer maps is a bit buggy. There seems to be a problem downloading/updating the data. What "worked" for me was:

1) Before you want to export it, change the rendering style of your main map to rectangle (in item properties -> main properties).

2) save everything and quit qgis.

3) reopen qgis and your print composer file without touching anything and export.

If this sounds absurd and stupid, congratulations, you are right, because it is...

Comment: Thanx Leander, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Yeah, such a weird hack is not reliable, but thought that it might work. I suggest moving this to gis.stackexchange.com - it's a plain GIS problem and you might get better help there. You can flag your own post as "off topic -> belongs to other stack exchange site" and get it moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my problems was resolved by rather using the QuickMapServices plugin rather than Openlayers. Seems like Openlayers and print composer does not work well because Openlayers needs to be set to the actual page size.